# qxmpp - getting list of all accounts being registered on openfire server

Tags: qt, openfire, qxmpp

Is there any way to get list of users/account registered on server?
Now I'm getting roster, but I would like to get not only roster but also every user jid registered to server.
 - openfire server
 - Qt
 - qxmpp library

Comment: Possibly just adding noise here.. but maybe [this XEP](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0133.html) will clue you in?  A total stab in the dark on my part.

Comment: But if it will work for not-admin accounts? Because I want to get list by not-admin user. I would like to have a possibility to see all users, when for example I want to add some users to my contact list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried with qxmpp, but my openfire installation has a plugin for [XEP-0055: Jabber Search](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0055.html). Using miranda IM, I can find all contancts in the server by searching for * (search service is search.my.xmpp.domain).
I don't know whether this plugin was part of the original installation or I had to install it separately.

Doing a quick search, qxmpp seems not to have an existing xep-0055 implementation, so you will either have to write one by yourself or maybe you can use the implementation linked in this post on [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/qxmpp/VSuJHQB3J2Q).

Comment: Yes, I have already found that XEP-0055 doesn't have an implementation in qxmpp, so I do it myself. But thanks